# How to identify the hard drive with the OS installed using Ansible?

Tags: linux, ansible

I have an Ubuntu server, with 2 drives `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc`. The OS is installed under `/dev/sdb`. Now, I am trying to write an Ansible playbook which will identify whether the particular partition contains the OS. I tried using the `lsblk` command which returns that the drive `/dev/sdb` is partitioned. But no partition table exists for `/dev/sdc/`.

Any examples on how to achieve this? My current playbook looks like:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
   - name: Get list of mounted hard drives
     command: 'lsblk'
     register: result
   - name: Create variable block_devices
     set_fact:
       block_devices: "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"
   - debug:
       var: block_devices
```

This playbook returns the available partitions. From this output how to implement the OS installation check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `rootfs` is gathered in [`ansible_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts) and does not need to be "extracted" via shell.

Here's how to access it:

`# cat play.yml`

```yaml
---
- name: display rootfs partition
  hosts: all
  become: yes
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:
   - name: print root partition
     shell: echo "{{ ansible_cmdline.root }}" > /tmp/rootfs_part
```

```
# ansible-playbook play.yml -i localhost,

PLAY [display rootfs partition] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [print root partition] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

# cat /tmp/rootfs_part
/dev/mapper/mirror-root
```